# Is it possible to use wildcards with tkinter Canvas '.find_withtag'?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I need to run a for loop that runs the same function on all items with a certain substring. I tried:

```
for i in range(len(self.canvas.find_withtag('*label*')):
    #do this
```

with the intention that if I have three items with the tags label0, label1, and label2, the for loop would run three times. What would be the best way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use wildcards with tkinter Canvas '.find_withtag'?

No, you cannot use wildcards.

You must specify an object id, a tag, or a logical expression of tags and ids. Here is what the canonical documentation on how to specify tags:

> When specifying items in canvas widget commands, if the specifier is an integer then it is assumed to refer to the single item with that id. If the specifier is not an integer, then it is assumed to refer to all of the items in the canvas that have a tag matching the specifier. The symbol tagOrId is used below to indicate that an argument specifies either an id that selects a single item or a tag that selects zero or more items.
>
> *tagOrId* may contain a logical expressions of tags by using operators:
>   “**&&**”, “**||**”, “**^**”, “**!**”, and parenthesized subexpressions. For example:
>
> `.c find withtag {(a&&!b)||(!a&&b)}`
>
> or equivalently:
>
> `.c find withtag {a^b}`
>
> will find only those items with either “a” or “b” tags, but not
>   both.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bryan Oakley has already pointed out in his answer, there's nothing built into `tkinter` that does what you want — but fortunately it's fairly easy to create your own function with that functionality. The example below provides the same simple shell-style wildcard character matching that the [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) module supports for file names.

Here's is what I mean:

```
from fnmatch import fnmatch

def find_withtag(canvas, pattern):
    """ Returns a list of the object IDs of the object or objects that match the
        pattern given. Supports shell-style wildcards characters "*" and "?".
    """
    ids = []
    for id in canvas.find_all():
        if any(fnmatch(tag, pattern) for tag in canvas.gettags(id)):
            ids.append(id)
    return ids
```